# How can I get all of my photos off of Flickr?

Tags: flickr

I have decided to no longer pay for a Flickr pro account and I would like to batch download all of my photos I have stored there. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Try [Downloader](http://janten.com/downloadr/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Migratr](http://www.callingshotgun.net/about/migratr/) is a usefull utility that lets you copy your photos from different sharing services using your hard drive as temporary storage. You can also download content to your hard drive without migrating it.

It supports multiple services including:

- Photobucket
- Flickr
- Picassa
- Faces.com
- AOL Pictures
- Phanfare
- Zooomr
- SmugMug

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do it before your account expires, otherwise you'll only have access to the last 200

[Bulkr](http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr) is an Air app I saw on [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5553663/bulkr-downloads-flickr-photos-to-your-desktop) but haven't used yet