# How to download all photos that I uploaded to Flickr into my computer?

Tags: flickr, export, osx

[Related thread but for Microsoft Windows, my question is for Mac OS X 10.5.8](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/333/11640)

I found [all tools only to upload mass photos from local computer to Flickr here](http://www.flickr.com/tools/), how can I download all of my photos automatically from Flickr to my computer?

Note: I've once been able to synchronize my Flickr with my iPhoto long time ago, I've never opened this app for a long time (for years), now I forgot how to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr - a cross-platform app, which is very neat.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Flick and Share: http://www.flickandshare.com
It's a free web service that allows Flickr users to generate a short-link to automatically download all the set's pictures in high-resolution.
Generated links are private so you can use it for your backup but can also be shared with friends if you need to let someone download pictures of an event (even private ones can be shared).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Photo Grabbr](http://www.malarkeysoftware.com/projects_PhotoGrabbr.html).

Here is a tutorial for it: http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/06/25/how-to-download-all-of-your-flickr-photos-using-os-x/

> Whatever your reason, downloading all of your Flickr photos at once is pretty easy, with the help of Photo Grabbr.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. I'm trying it right now while studying both links you mentioned. I wonder it always said User not found although I put my correct flickr account : [ariekusumaatmaja](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ariekusumaatmaja/)

Comment: Hm, I seem to have successfully authorized it, but it still doesn't work as I expected, now the status is saying "Invalid frob"

Answer (score 0):

To download your entire Flickr collection on your Mac in the original size and resolution, trust [PicBackMan](https://www.picbackman.com/flickr-photo-video-bulk-uploader-for-mac/). PicBackMan downloads 100s and 1000s of photos from your Flickr account to your local machine, almost automatically.

All you need to do is, download and install PicBackMan. Register your account. Connect your Flickr account and specify a location for PicBackMan to save downloaded photos. That’s it.

PicBackMan is also packed with other useful features like (a) de-dupe, (b) tagging (c) migration and lot more. Downloading Flickr photos using PicBackMan is even faster than Flickr’s own uploader.